# Pdf Barcode128 Line Width For Zebra

Tags: php, pdf, barcode, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I'm printing on a zebra printer, but barcodes are failing the decodability score
I tried different widths, but not sure what the correct one should be, when the same pdf is printed in a normal printer the barcode decodability is much higher
zebras are supposed to be 203dpi, should then the lines in PDF be 0.375mm to print correctly?
any suggestion would be appreciated
and can't use ZPL for this project

Comment: This is this question tagged `php`?

Comment: I'm using fpdf to generate the pdf

Comment: Sure, you also use an operating system, a computer brand, electricity, yet you did not use such tags? Why not? Correct: because it is irrelevant for the question asked... :-)

Comment: well fpdf is a php library that someone may have used to generate a barcode128 to use in zebra printers